# Show that $\min(X,Y)$ has geometric distribution

Tags: probability

$X,Y$ - random variables,
$X-Geom(p)$
$Y-Geom(r)$
$$P(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$$
$$P(Y=k) = (1-r)^{k-1}r$$
$X,Y$ are independent. Show that $Z=\min(X,Y)-Geom(t)$

My attempt:
$P(\min(X,Y))=P(X=k\wedge Y\ge k) + P(Y=k\wedge X\ge k) - P(Y=k\wedge X=k) = P(X=k)\cdot P(Y\ge k) + P(Y=k)\cdot P(X\ge k) - P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=k)$
And I don't idea what can I do now to finish it.

Comment: You should really use, for example, $X \sim Geom(p)$ instead of $-$. The code is \sim.

Comment: And by the way, what is $t$?

Comment: There are several posts of exactly the same question. Judging by the content, it's hard to decide which one should be deemed the original and the others duplicate. In chronological order: [90782](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90782), [845706](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845706), [1040620](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040620), [1169142](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169142), and [1207241](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207241).

Answer (score 3):

With the minimum, a bit of cleverness is necessary:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\min(X, Y) \leq z\right) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\min(X, Y) > z\right) \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\text{both }X \text{ and }Y > z\right) \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X > z)\mathbb{P}(Y>z)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Note the above is the distribution function of $Z$. Now 
$$\mathbb{P}(X > z) = \sum\limits_{k = z+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p = p[(1-p)^{z}+(1-p)^{z+1}+\cdots] = p(1-p)^{z}\left[\dfrac{1}{1-(1-p)}\right] = (1-p)^{z}\text{, } \quad |1-p|<1\text{.}$$
You can find a similar result for $\mathbb{P}(Y > z)$.

Use the resulting equation of $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq z)$ to derive an explicit formula for $\mathbb{P}\left(Z = z\right)$ by using that 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(Z = z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq z\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq z-1\right)\text{.}$$