# Minimum of two geometric distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent discrete  random variables, both having the geometric distribution, $X$ with parameter $p$ and $Y$ with parameter $r$. How do I show that $U=\min \{X,Y\}$ has the geometric distribution with parameter $p+r-pr$?

Comment: Find the probability that $X \gt z$ *and* $Y \gt z$

Comment: But what is $z$?

Comment: a non-negative integer

Comment: There are several posts of exactly the same question. Judging by the content, it's hard to decide which one should be deemed the original and the others duplicate. In chronological order: [90782](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90782), [845706](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845706), [1040620](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040620), [1056296](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056296), and [1207241](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207241).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $\mathbf{P}(U \geq n) = \mathbf{P}(X \geq n, Y \geq n)$ by the definition of $U$. By independance and by the properties of geometric distributions, this is equal to $\mathbf{P}(X \geq n) \mathbf{P}(Y \geq n) = (1 - p)^n(1-r)^n = (1 - r - p + pr)^n$.

Define $q = r+p - pr$ so that $\mathbf{P}(U \geq n) = (1 - q)^n$. You should easily be able to prove now that $U$ follows a geometric law with parameter $q$ (try to calculate $\mathbf{P}(U = n)$ for example).

**Note**. To me, a geometric r.v. is a r.v. such that $\mathbf{P}(X = k) = (1-p)^k p$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.