# Minimum of two geometric random variables is geometric

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two independent r.v's with geometric distribution: parameters $\lambda, \mu $, respectively. Let $Z = \min(X, Y) $. Show $Z$ is geometric with parameter $\lambda \mu $.

$$Attempt $$

By hypothesis, I know $P^X( A \in X) = \sum_{j \in A} \lambda^j (1-\lambda) $ and $P^Y(B \in Y) = \sum_{j \in B} \mu^j(1 - \mu) $. Next, I have

$$ P^Z(Z \in C) = \sum_{j \in C} P(Z = j ) = \sum_{j \in C} P( \min(X,Y) = j) $$

We know $X,Y \geq \min(X,Y) $, therefore, $P( \min(X,Y) =j ) = P(X \geq j, Y \geq j ) $ and since $X,Y$ are independent, we have $P(X \geq j, Y \geq j ) = P(X \geq j) P(Y \geq j )$. Here is where I am stuck. Am I on the right track ?

Comment: Note, if the minimum is equal to $j$, then *at least one* of the two variables must equal to $j$. $$\begin{align}P(\min(X,Y)=j) & = P((X=j\cap Y\geq j)\cup(X>j\cap Y=j)) \\[1ex] & = P(X=j)P(Y\geq j)+P(X>j)P(Y=j)\end{align}$$

Comment: I found several earlier posts of exactly the same question. Judging by the content, it's hard to decide which one should be deemed the original and the others duplicate. In chronological order: [90782](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90782), [845706](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845706), [1040620](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040620), [1056296](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056296), and [1169142](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169142).

Answer (score 2):

Use distribution function:

$$P(\min(X,Y) \le x) = 1 - P(\min(X,Y) \ge x) = 1 - P(X \ge x, Y\ge x) = 1 - P(X \ge x) P(Y \ge x)$$

Now compute that and recognise the distribution function of a geometric distribution

Comment: Im confused, inst it what I have just done ?

Comment: @Anonaki no,  you started with a general event $Z$ and wrote that $P(\min(X,Y) = j) = P(X\ge j, Y\ge j) $ which is not true

Comment: Why is not true? isnt $X,Y \geq \min(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: @Anonaki yes, that is true. But it doesn't imply what you've written.. Try to think about why and construct s counterexample :-)

Comment: What is $P( \min(X,Y) \leq x ) $. the $x$ confuses me. Can you explain ?

Comment: @Anonaki its the point in which we are calculating the distribution function $F$ :$F(x) = P(X \in (-\infty, x]) = P(X \le x)$

Comment: but geometric rv is discrete i think

Comment: @Anonaki indeed. So what? Distribution functions exists for every probability distribution. Search for "distribution function geometric" to actually look at it and understand what it is

Comment: I am so confused. I learned that the distribution of geometric r.v is $P(X = j) = p^j(1-p) $ where $p$ is parameter. IT doesnt look like your distribution.

Comment: @anonaki we are using different terms :-) I am referring to the cumulative distribution function, or cdf:-)

Answer (score 0):

Given that $X,Y$ are two independent, geometic distributed random variables with parameters $\lambda, \mu$ (respectively), then each is a count failures before a success event (say $S_X,S_Y$) occurs in a series of Bernoulli trials with success probability $\lambda, \mu$.

Thus $Z:=\min(X,Y)$ measures the count of failed trials before *either* success event first occurs.   As these events are independent, the unioned success event has probability:

$$P(S_X\cup S_Y) = \lambda +\mu-\lambda \mu$$

$Z$ is thus a geometric distributed random variable with parameter: $\lambda +\mu-\lambda \mu$